# Simple Play/Pause button getting the URL file from ACF wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, elementor

i have tried to figure out a way to add a simple play/pause button in my wordpress website. The URL file should be dynamic and change for every post.
I am using elementor to create post/page layout.

I was able to add the complete media player, dynamic using a code snippet, but this will add play, pause, volume control etc. I just want a play/pause button with the icon changing.

I have tried to check online for tutorials and asking chatgpt but i cannot figure out a solution.
This is the code i used:

```
    <?php
if (function_exists('get_field')) {
  $audio_url = get_field('traccia');
  if ($audio_url) {
    echo '<audio controls>';
    echo '<source src="' . $audio_url . '" type="audio/mpeg">';
    echo 'Your browser does not support the audio element.';
    echo '</audio>';
  }
}
?>
```